# comprehensive primer on slugs and or pretty URLs in django

Tags: django, pretty-urls

On the official django site, for version 1.6, under 'design philosophy' , it says pretty URLs should be easier to make than ugly ones. But when I search the site, I can't find any other use of the word 'pretty'. So how, or where, is the step by step guide for newbies like me to make pretty URLs? I also think the official documentation on slugs is pretty sparse. Are slugs the same as pretty URLs in django? I've seen some answers on Stack Overflow that give bits and pieces to some of my questions, but what I'd really like is a thorough discussion of this topic. Can anyone point me to something like that? Thx.

Comment: "pretty urls" isn't a technical term. It's meant literally, as in urls that are pretty (readable, comprehensive, concise, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a definition of "pretty" as it relates to URLs anywhere. However, what the designers probably meant was readable ones like `mysite.com/category/item/` rather than obscure id params such as `mysite.com/shop?item_id=45754dghrs3467`.